# Check if coercion would be successful?

Tags: raku

Given

```
my $t=+"aaa";
```

is it possible tho check if the coercion will succeed (I know that it doesn't here)  before using $t ?

BTW: What I really want to do is check if a string is a valid Integer. I know that I can use a regex for that purpose, but I suppose that there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+'aaa'` results in a Failure which is a kind of Nil which is a bit like an undefined value.
Which means you can use anything that works with them.

```perl6
my $t = +$s with +$s; # $t remains undefined
```

```perl6
my $t = +$s // 0; # $t === 0
```

```perl6
my $t = (+$s).defined ?? +$s !! 0;
```

Since what you want to do is check if it is an Int

```perl6
my $t = +$s ~~ Int ?? +$s !! 0; # Failures aren't a type of Int
```

```perl6
my $t = 0;
with +$s {
  when Int { $t = $_ }
  default { ... } # +$s is defined
} else {
  ... # optional else clause
}
```

Comment: your first version could also be written as `my $t = $_ with +$s;` as `with` is a topicalizer

Comment: @Christoph Yeah I was thinking of `with` as a **defined if**, which would only store it in the topic variable if you used a pointy block. ( I played a small part of its creation by pointing out how `if defined $a.method -> $b {...}` couldn't put the value of `$a.method` in `$b` ) Since that was the main impetus for its creation, of course it would always topicalize.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another version:

```
my $t = +"aaa" orelse note "could not coerce to numeric type";
say $t.^name; # Failure
```

`orelse` is the low-precedence version of `//`. In this version, the assignment to `$t` still happens, but the check for definedness handles the failure, ie it won't blow up and raise an error.

Comment: Actually `orelse` also topicalizes. `my $t = +"aaa" orelse note .message`

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it around a try block to catch the exception.

```
my $t;
try {
  $t = +"aaa";
  CATCH { say "the coercion didn't work" when X::Str::Numeric; }
}
```

Comment: That should be `CATCH { default { say "the coercion didn't work" }}` or `CATCH { when X::Str::Numeric { say "the coercion didn't work" }}` or a base type of `X::Str::Numeric` otherwise Perl 6 couldn't tell if you meant to handle the error, or if you re-threw it. You could also do `try {...} or say ...`